# Any recommendations on commentaries / rebuttals of Heidegger's Question Concerning Technology?

Tags: heidegger, philosophy-of-technology

I'm looking for recommendations of commentaries, rebuttals or relevant papers on a Heideggerian approach to examining the essence of technology (famously in 'The Question Concerning Technology' but elsewhere as well). Anybody here able to help me out? I'm also particularly interested in similar works musing on the essence of the Internet (as a technological concept) in particular. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yuk Hui's new work, *Cosmotechnics: The question concerning technology in China* seems relevant here

Comment: Part II of Bernard Stiegler's Technics and Time is largely devoted to critiquing Heidegger's approach to the issue of techne with a primary focus on the issue of access to authentic temporality through objects. It is sympathetic to the universe that Heidegger's questions opens up, but critical of what it elides or obscures. Central to his critique is his reading of Simondon and Leroi-Gourhan and their work challenges Heidegger's understanding of human/technological evolution.